# adzerk having difficulty serving ads to facebook.so?

Tags: bug, status-completed, advertising

Might just be me or something temporary, but switching from stackoverflow.com to facebook.stackoverflow.com, I momentarily see the 'space' where the ad should be, then it collapses.

Answer (score 2):

That's already fixed in the code (and actually not related to fb.so), just not deployed yet. Should be shortly.